# ORA-00907 on WebSphere with SpringData

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, websphere

I have the following problem. I try to run my application on the IBM WebSphere 9.0.0.9. My application uses Spring Data. I have very simple repository with simple method:

```
public interface TerminalGroupRepository extends JpaRepository<TerminalGroup, String> {
    List<TerminalGroup> findByNodeNodeIdIn(Collection<Long> nodeIds);
}
```

For unknown reason, when I try to run this on WebSphere, the following exception is thrown:

```
 Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.7.WAS-v20180710-6c446ab): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException 
 Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 
 Error Code: 907 
 Call: SELECT t1.terminalgroupid, t1.DESCRIPTION, t1.NAME, t1.nodeid FROM dm_terminalgroup t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN node t0 ON (t0.nodeid = t1.nodeid) WHERE (t0.nodeid IN ((?,?))) 
 bind => [2 parameters bound] 
 Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=TerminalGroup sql="SELECT t1.terminalgroupid, t1.DESCRIPTION, t1.NAME, t1.nodeid FROM dm_terminalgroup t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN node t0 ON (t0.nodeid = t1.nodeid) WHERE (t0.nodeid IN (?))") 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:684) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2061) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:586) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:261) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:262) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:248) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:319) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:715) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2772) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2725) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:559) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1175) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:911) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1134) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:460) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1222) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2899) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1863) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1845) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1810) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258) 
 ... 158 more 
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494) 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446) 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054) 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623) 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252) 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612) 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226) 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:59) 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:747) 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:904) 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1082) 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780) 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343) 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3822) 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165) 
 at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecuteQuery(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1228) 
 at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:746) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1009) 
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:644) 
 ... 179 more 
 Caused by: Error : 907, Position : 155, Sql = SELECT t1.terminalgroupid, t1.DESCRIPTION, t1.NAME, t1.nodeid FROM dm_terminalgroup t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN node t0 ON (t0.nodeid = t1.nodeid) WHERE (t0.nodeid IN ((:1 ,:2 ))), OriginalSql = SELECT t1.terminalgroupid, t1.DESCRIPTION, t1.NAME, t1.nodeid FROM dm_terminalgroup t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN node t0 ON (t0.nodeid = t1.nodeid) WHERE (t0.nodeid IN ((?,?))), Error Msg = ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498) 
 ... 197 more
```

What is going on there?? Thank you for any piece of advice...

Comment: Can you please provide more information concerning your usecase? Are you using the CriteriaBuilder API? Can you provide how you construct your query? This is important in order to determine if the fix for https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349477 is the same for this situation.

Comment: @WillDazey everything is there. It's Spring Data, so I don't construct any query on my own.

Answer (score 0):

In clauses were broken in EclipseLink and to some extend they are still broken.

See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349477 and referenced issues.

The current snapshot of Spring Data JPA contains a workaround which should work as long as the collection you pass as a parameter isn't null.

See https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-433

Answer (score 0):

I did in another way, I implemented it with Query DSL. But such a bug is frustrating...